# Javascript to read nested Json items

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xml, cross-domain

I have a JSON and i want to read the title and link inside the item using Javascript.

```
{
    "rss": {
        "version": "2.0",
        "content": "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/",
        "channel": {
            "title": " National",
            "pubDate": "Mon, 06 Jul 2015 10:56:29 +1000",
            "lastBuildDate": "Mon, 06 Jul 2015 10:56:29 +1000",

            "generator": "news_national_3354",
            "ttl": "5",
            "item": [
                {
                    "title": "Australia’s biggest housing demolition begins",
                    "link": "http://www.news.com.au/lifestyle/health/mr-fluffy-housing-demolitions-begin/story-fneuzlbd-1227430208115?from=public_rss",
                },
                {
                    "title": "Barnaby Joyce pulls out of Q&A",
                    "link": "http://www.news.com.au/national/barnaby-joyce-pulls-out-of-scheduled-qa-appearance/story-fncynjr2-1227429015164?from=public_rss",

                },
                {
                    "title": "Children who murder parents",
                    "link": "http://www.news.com.au/national/crime/one-parent-is-killed-a-month-by-their-child-crime-statistics-reveal/story-fns0kb1g-1227428117585?from=public_rss",

                }


            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I do not want to use PHP. I am reading Xmls from different domain server and i was getting `Cross Domain Error`. i found [this](http://blogs.agilefaqs.com/2013/07/17/fetching-cross-domain-xml-in-javascript-simple-solution/) solution to convert xml into JSON. I am able to read the xml from different domain and get it as a JSON. Is this solution efficient enough to use in the live project or i should not be using Javascript to fetch XMLs from a different server. Please advice me in this issue. Thanks

Comment: **JSONP** might be what you're looking for to cope with cross-domain access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The questions of "efficiency" are somewhat controversial because the question arises of what do we mean by "efficiency"?

Is fetching JSON over XML more efficient? Most definitely yes. JSON by it's definition is more suitable for javascript because... well let's take a look at the name:

> javascript object nation

Meanwhile there is little to think with regards to client side. As noted [here](http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/08/xml-json-performance) there are more important aspects to consider, namely:

a) Using HTTP compression
b) Optimization of mark-up for querying

To give you [another perspective](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/604720/JSON-vs-XML-Some-hard-numbers-about-verbosity):

> In my humble opinion what makes JSON the natural choice for a lot of
>   applications is not its inherent qualities, though real as
>   demonstrated in the above article, but its strong integration into the
>   web ecosystem because JSON is the native way of representing
>   JavaScript objects trees.

And there's little to be added from here. The question mainly deals with where you are fetching the information from. Javascript operates on the client side, so it's not really an issue to parse it and convert it to JSON. Though if using JSON directly you could remove that parsing. But it is perfectly fine to use XML in a situation like this, in fact this is exactly why it was created, so it is most definitely a viable option. In the end it boils down to the question of how performance and scalability is important to you. If you set up the service to deliver JSON from the very beginning, it will be easier for you if you want to scale, as I'd argue that generating XML is more difficult, not to mention again the need to parse it anyway.But in on purpose show you two conflicting opinions, and I can add the [third one](http://www.codetails.com/2013/10/23/which-one-is-better-json-vs-xml-serialization/) which summarizes the differences in data storage (which rarely is an issue these days, again only with big projects) and there's little difference in other contexts:

> Winner: JSON without compression; With compression, minor gain by
>   using JSON

But if you are not in a situation where you will have tens of thousands of requests and a bloated client side javascript application, it will virtually have no difference for you. And even if it did, compressing it is way more important than choosing one over the other.

I will repeat what I said earlier, both JSON and XML were created for exactly the same purpose - data serialization. So they are by all means interchangeable and most definitely both are efficient solutions. However, consider only on how much your project will scale and even so this has largely to do with personal preferences.

As for cross-domain RESTs and stuff like that, please check out [CORS](http://www.webdevdoor.com/jquery/cross-domain-browser-json-ajax/).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. By efficiency i meant 'is it reliable'. If you check my link it shows how to read xml from cross domain server. i was concerned about the solution of bypassing the cross domain error and make it work for all browser.

Comment: Well it's as reliable as Yahoo is, as you are using Yahoo as a proxy.

Comment: btw, did you do a "console.log" of the response on your own server or is that copy in the question from YQL console?

Comment: nop i did a console.log and i am getting rss in a JSON format

Comment: and if you write console.log(response.rss.channel.item), do you get just an array with items?

Comment: yup i am getting the data

Comment: but then what's the problem if you write: 

for (var i = 0; i < response.rss.channel.item.length; i++) {
  console.log(response.rss.channel.item[i].title);
  console.log(response.rss.channel.item[i].link);
}

? :)

Comment: i am doing like this   var response = JSON.stringify(results.query.results);
                var response = JSON.parse(response);
                console.log(response);
                var items = response.rss.channel.item;

                for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    console.log(items[i].title);
                    console.log(items[i].link);
     console.log(items[i].source.content);
                }

Comment: And does it work? Didn't you say that you already get a JSON? Why the stringify and parse part?

Answer (score 1):

You must first transform the JSON into a JS Object using JSON.parse:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
```

Them you can walk in the object normally:

```
var title = obj.rss.channel.title;
var link = obj.rss.content;
```

Comment: how to iterate through items?

Comment: well i am getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o so i am using var response = JSON.stringify(results.query.results); and then i am getting  Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined error

Answer (score 1):

Once you've set the JSON response to a variable (`data` in the example below), you can parse the JSON and then use it like any other JavaScript object. Example:

```
var response = JSON.parse(data);
var items = response.rss.channel.item;

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  console.log(items[i].title);
  console.log(items[i].link);
}
```

Comment: well i am getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o so i am using var response = JSON.stringify(results.query.results); and then i am getting  Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined error

Answer (score 1):

If you received `JSON` data, you don't have to convert to `JSON`, just only read.

```
var items = data.rss.channel.item;

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  console.log(items[i].title);
  console.log(items[i].link);
}
```

Comment: i am getting an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined

Comment: Do you receive a JSON or string?

Comment: string var obj = JSON.stringify(results.query.results);